# IP Default crypto isakmp key with specific keys as well

Tags: networking, cisco, ipsec

I am wondering if anyone knows how isakmp keys work when there is one for any ip and then another entry for a specific entry.  Will the specific always take precedence?

For example, if I have `crypto isakmp key foo 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` and `crypto isakmp key baz 12.12.12.12`, will baz be the for 12.12.12.12 and foo for anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that it was true that the specific entries were taking precedence.